# C# Mono on mac - compile and run another project with code

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, xbuild

I am trying to build an automatic download, compile & run program for a project just to make it easier for other users on mac and myself so we do not have to do everything over and over as the project progresses. I cant find anything on how to compile and run a C# monodevelop project with code when i google. Does anyone here know how it could be done?

thanks

Edit: using xbuild as mentioned below compiles the project, but i cannot seem to find a command to run the build? the only output seems to be .exe and that launches vmware when i try to run, is there som command that i add somewhere? like execute

```
tar -xf sources.tar.gz
cd *project*
xbuild project.sln
```

Answer (score 5):

To build applications you can use `gmcs` , to run then you can use `mono`.
From a Terminal shell, you can try it out:

```
$ gmcs hello.cs
$ mono hello.exe
Hello, World
```

Comment: FYI, it might be `mcs` instead of `gmcs`.

Comment: `csc hello.cs` and `mono hello.exe`

Answer (score 4):

The full answer of course depends on the sources concerned and the build system it uses. For mono relates sources you can often do the following:

```
tar -xf sources.tar.gz
cd sources
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If you have a .sln file and csproj files, you need to use `mdtool` or `xbuild`. `mdtool` comes with monodevelop, `xbuild` comes with mono. Both understand visual studio solution and csproj files and will build them. xbuild a mono [equivalent of msbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build).

Comment: I am completely new to terminal though I did create a file. touch filename pico filename then i added your code. saved and chmodded to 755. I put the file in the directory of the downloaded source.tar.gz that my program does, but when i try to run it it says it cant find the file.

Im trying to run a monodevelop project.

Comment: @ViktorAlm you will have to run the script, "./filename" should do it

Comment: Error opening archive: Failed to open './sources.tar.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: change to the directory you download to, perhaps 'cd ~/Downloads'

Comment: @ViktorAlm I'm guessing your source archive isn't called 'sources.tar.gz' :)

Comment: I have fixed that, it was just me not being used to the terminal. I want to compile and run the file and this just seems to compile